# Parameters positioning in polymorphic functions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, polymorphism, default-value

I am new to kotlin and I would like to have two polymorphic functions with a default parameter, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code:

```
private fun add(request: Request, share: Boolean = false, number : Int){
   Do something ... 
}
private fun add(key: String, share: Boolean = false){
   Do something ... 
}
```

My problem is that I can't use the default value because the compiler doesn't seem to infer it.

```
add(request,  number)
```

When I do this, meaning that I want to use the first function with the default value of the boolean, I get an error saying that it requires a string and it found a request.

What I think is that the compiler is confused with default values and polymorphism; it doesn't seem to know witch function to use. Is there any ways to fix this or do I have to explicitly declare the default value each time making the default value useless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the parameter with default value on 3rd place in first function so it would become

`private fun add(request: Request, number : Int, share: Boolean = false){
   Do something ...`

it will work.
you can solve this by named arguments, for example
if you call `add(request = request,  number = number)` It will work as well

Comment: Thanks it's work, can you explain why it work this way ?

Comment: Parameters are passed as position-based arguments and first argument corresponds to first parameter and so on. However it can be solved by named arguments. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Answer by Abubakar works and recommended way - keep the default parameters at the last. However, what you have would also work. Just make sure to use named parameters for parameters after the default value.

```
add(request, number = 5) // Or add(request, number= myNumberValue)
```

will also work.

Answer (score 0):

By default arguments are position-based, alternatively you have to specify parameter name like in the example below:

```kotlin
fun addName(name: String, newUser: Boolean, surname: String = "") {

}

fun addName(name: String) {

}


class Person() {
    init {
        addName(name = "Johnny", surname = "BeGood", newUser = true) // Using 1st function with mixed positions parameters
        addName("Jack") // Using 2nd function
    }
}
```